# Test case for 100% branch coverage with no fault?

Tags: java, junit, testcase

The problem statement is

*A method that has a zero fault that you can write a test suite to that has 100% statement coverage but doesn't find the fault and another test suite that has 100% branch coverage that does reveal the fault?*

Here is the method I wrote for the same

```
public  faultyMethod1(int x, int y) {
  int X =x;
  int Y = y;

  if (Y !=0){
    Z = X/Y;
  } else {
    System.out.println("Sorry. That's an DiviDeByZeroException");
  }
}

faultyMethod1 (1,2);
faultyMethod1 (2,0);
```

The above code to achieve test suite that has 100% branch coverage that does reveal the fault"

What about *test suite to that has 100% statement coverage but doesn't find the fault* ?

Comment: Where is the fault? (Besides that `Z` is never declared and never used.)

Comment: that is just a psuedo code :-)  the fault is x/y. which can throw division by zero.

Comment: But you have a check for this. The code will never divide by zero.

Comment: that is the reaso it is not 100% statement coverage. I need to make that 100%

Comment: I think you should pick a more sensible example where there is an actual programming error. It is not clear to me what the current method is supposed to do and what would be a “fault”. If it prints “sorry”, this doesn't seem to be a bug.

Comment: Hmm..Can you show me some example?? which matches the both conditions.

Answer (score 6):

Let's make another example...

```
// The method, according to our imaginary specification, should do:
//  return x * y, IF x is less than 2
//  return x + y, in any other case
public int doSomething(int x, int y) {

if (x < 2 ) {
   return x * x;  // this is our bug, it SHOULD be x * y
}

return x + y;

}
```

Now imagine we have two tests:

```
assertEquals(0, doSomething( 0, 12) );  // works, as 0 * 0 == 0 * 12
assertEquals(20, doSomething( 10, 10 ) ); // works fine
```

So, now we have 100% test coverage (because the x < 2 branch has been covered, as well as the other one). But we didn't find the bug, since using zero as value for x hides it (since 0 * something is always 0, y is irrelevant). We would have needed something like this...

```
assertEquals(12, doSomething( 1, 12) );  // fails, because it will be 1*1 == 1
```

The same problem can occur for any other situation, including a division by zero. Can't imagine a good example, but I guess you get the basic idea how having a 100% coverage does not mean finding 100% of all bugs. (A cool way to find them would be mutation testing, but that's a pretty advanced topic.)

Comment: While this example indeed shows a bug that is not caught by a test suite with full statement coverage, it doesn't directly answer the question because the inferior test suite also has full branch coverage.

Comment: Sorry, don't get the point, the example has also full branch coverage as every if possibility (there is only one) is run through...?

Comment: Yes, and that's the point. It is not an example of a test suite with full statement coverage but incomplete branch coverage that misses a bug that would have been found had the branch coverage been complete. It was my (possibly wrong) understanding of the question that such example was sought.

Answer (score 0):

How about confusing a logical AND with an OR?

```
// This method must never throw; on error, it shall return -1.
int foo(final String s, final int n) {
    if (s != null || n != 0) {
        return s.length() / n;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The following test inputs achieve 100 % statement coverage and don't unveil the bug.

```
assert foo("everything is fine", 6) == 3;  // happy path, ok
assert foo(null, 0) == -1;                 // error path, ok
```

The test-suite has not foll branch-coverage, however, because the two expressions ORed together evaluate to the same value in each case. Adding the following two test cases completes branch coverage and exposes the bug.

```
assert foo("bingo", 0) == -1;  // ArithmeticException
assert foo(null, 4) == -1;     // NullPointerException
```

As a matter of fact, these four inputs together also achieve *path coverage* which is an even stronger requirement than branch coverage.

Comment: The ask is specifically for a set of test suites such that the 100% path coverage *does not* reveal the fault. But 100% branch coverage does.